# Font rendering bigger in cordova canvas than in mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, fonts

I'm facing a weird issue in my Cordova Application on Android.

I am drawing text to a canvas, like this:

```
context.textAlign = "center";
context.textBaseline = "middle";
context.font = "5px GameFont";
context.fillText("...", x, y);
```

However, the font **renders bigger** in the cordova application (Which uses the same browser view than my mobile chrome):

[image]

I'm loading the font via css:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GameFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('fonts/work-sans-v4-latin-600.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/work-sans-v4-latin-600.woff') format('woff');
}
```

---

**Things I tried**

*Using a default font*:

I tried using `Arial` and the same issue occurs.

*Ensuring the font is preloaded:*

`<span style="font-family: GameFont;" class="fontPreload">_</span>`

*Setting/normalizing css text properties:*

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-break: auto;
line-height: 1.2;
text-transform: none;
white-space: normal;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
font-stretch: 100%;
```

*Preloading the font using document.fonts*

```
const font = new FontFace(familyName, "url(" + url + ")", descriptors);
font.load().then(() => {
    document.fonts.add(font)
});
```

---

**Anybody already faced this issue? How can it get solved?**

Comment: What you should check is the font size setting in Android Setting and see if they make any impact in rendering.

Comment: @Gungnir actually this seems to be the case! Any idea how I could prevent this?

Comment: So, after playing arround a bit, it seems that while most of the font is scaled, the canvas drawing is not affected, only the html content. Any other idea?

Comment: For a quick "fix" you should try -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; in your css but imo the real fix would be to use font size specified in dp instead of px. Also if you have access to android code you can force your locally loaded webview font size with this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.TextSize

Comment: @Gungnir I already have text-size-adjust in my css and it does not really do anything. I don't think it affects canvas rendering